# "Node.js is not installed". while trying to integrate android studio to AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm trying to integrate AWS to my android app and for that I followed there official [link](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/android).
after doing all the changes mentioned in the official link and net step was to build the project and here I see faced the following error.

[image: error image]

Node.js is currently installed on my (Windows)system.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> node -v
v12.18.1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm -v 
6.14.5
```

I went ahead and googled the error and saw there is already a git issue open for the same and it is resolved but I still see the same issue.

[git issue link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3745)

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try simply cleaning the project?

Comment: This worked for me ..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and could resolve it by restarting Android Studio. ("rebuild" etc. did not solve it)

Comment: Restarting android studio worked for me as well.