# node.js is not installed android studio gradle

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

guys,

I found the answer
[node-js-is-not-installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575787/node-js-is-not-installed-while-trying-to-integrate-android-studio-to-aws)
and I have the same problem

actually, I have nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4)
```

.
but if I try to build I coach Gradle exception like

```
Node.js is not installed. Visit https://nodejs.org/en/download/ to install it.
Open File
```

unfortunately, steps by [issues/3745](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3745) don't resolve it fo me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMxYo.png)

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had a identical problem earlier today. But I'm on a Mac. Same behaviour as you experienced.

I've try to reinstall node, and several rebuilding of my project but none of those worked.

In the end, I started over. Seems that the installation of the amplify cli did not went throught the previous time.

`npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`

But I've come to another problem with the manifest.xml right after that. I think both are related...

And adding this to my manifest did the job : 'tools:replace="android:name"' (for reference if this problem follow : https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/532 )

Answer (score 1):

Run this in your project directory and then resync:
`npx amplify-app --platform android`

At least, this helped me

Answer (score 0):

Did you install amplify using `sudo`? That has solved my problem.
Also using Mac OSX

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you may not have proper write permissions on node_modules folder, use chmod 777 your_node_module_folder

Comment: Using 777 to fix any permissions problems is the worst suggestion possible. Do not provide such tips. Maybe you read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271596/how-will-a-server-become-vulnerable-with-chmod-777